# How to make SQL query to get parent child data in group

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I have one customer table, and have parent and sub customer in same table with "ParentId" field relation. Table as below.

```
CustId      CustName    ParentId
----------------------------------
1           Cust1         0 
2           Cust2         0
3           Sub2Cust1     1
4           Cust3         0
5           Sub1Cust1     1
6           Sub1Cust2     2
7           Sub2Cust2     2
8           Sub4Cust1     1
9           Sub1Cust3     4
10          Sub3Cust1     1
```

What I want is from MS SQL Query so it keep parent and child record together, Like output as below:

```
CustId      CustName    ParentId
----------------------------------
1           Cust1          0 
5           Sub1Cust1      1
3           Sub2Cust1      1
10          Sub3Cust1      1
8           Sub4Cust1      1
2           Cust2          0
6           Sub1Cust2      2
7           Sub2Cust2      2
4           Cust3          0
9           Sub1Cust3      4
```

Can anybody please give me a hint how to do it with single query?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ORDER BY CASE  WHEN ParentId = 0 THEN CustID ELSE ParentId END ASC
,  CASE WHEN ParentId = 0 THEN 0 ELSE CustId END ASC  --to put the parent on top of the children, and keep the children in order
```

To order the children by name, rather than ID, simply do this instead:

```
ORDER BY CASE  WHEN ParentId = 0 THEN CustID ELSE ParentId END ASC
,  CASE WHEN ParentId = 0 THEN '0' ELSE CustName END ASC  --to put the parent on top of the children, and keep the children in order
```

Comment: yes you query look like partially work. if you see my output i want the output with ASC order of CustName for parent as well child

Comment: What I see in your output is that everything is ordered by ID.  If you want CustName to override ID in the ordering, please change your sample output to make it clear exactly what you mean.   This query will produce your sample output based on your sample data.

Comment: Edited my answer to the new output.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, you may need a recursive CTE.

Technically NOT one query, but this will support variable depth and your desired sorting

**Example**

```
;with cteP as (
      Select CustId
            ,ParentId 
            ,CustName 
            ,PathStr = cast(CustName as varchar(max))
      From   YourTable 
      Where  ParentId=0
      Union  All
      Select CustId  = r.CustId
            ,ParentId  = r.ParentId 
            ,CustName   = r.CustName
            ,HierID = P.PathStr+'>'+r.CustName
      From   YourTable r
      Join   cteP p on r.ParentId  = p.CustId )
Select CustId
      ,CustName 
      ,ParentId
 From cteP A
 Order By A.PathStr
```

**Returns**

```
CustId  CustName    ParentId
1       Cust1       0
3       Sub1Cust1   1
5       Sub2Cust1   1
8       Sub3Cust    1
10      Sub4Cust1   1
2       Cust2       0
6       Sub1Cust2   2
7       Sub2Cust2   2
4       Cust3       0
9       Sub1Cust3   4
```

Comment: yes with CTE it gives the output i want. but problem is to use in my case is there are lots other fields and apply search parameter also in that query, so i prefer if any single query without join give me output then it good. @Tab Allemen query works but only issue is child element and parent element i want in ASC order